# SVG masking clipPath dont work properly in a container in Chrome

Tags: html, css, svg, masking, clip-path

I try to mask an element with a SVG clip-path and followed this workaround: https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-svg-clipping/

Everthing works well in Chrome and Firefox, its seems to be the best solution.

But when i put the content in a container to center it, chrome is having problems with the mask. Firefox is centering the content while in chrome the mask seems to stick on the left side of the browser.

You can see it in this is the Fiddle:           https://jsfiddle.net/mideyahdotch/wk58Lq7h/2/

```
<style>
.container {
  width:1080px;
  margin:0 auto;
} 

.svg-clipped {
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#svgPath); 
  clip-path:url(#svgPath);
} 
</style>

<div class="container">
 <div class="svg-clipped">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1080x470">
 </div>
</div>

<svg height="0" width="0">
 <defs>
  <clipPath id="svgPath">
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.5794" 
    stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M0.4,467.35l1080-30.77V0.22L0.4-.28V467.35Z" />
  </clipPath>
 </defs>
</svg>
```

Anyone knows an answer to this issue?
Thanks for your support!

mideyah